# sed variable substitution not working

Tags: bash, unix, sed

This problems been driving me up the wall for a bit now, I've searched a ton and it seems like nobody elses solutions work for me...

```
sed "s|{{/each}}| -->\n $photostr |" $1
```

So I'm trying to end a comment, and slap in my photo string. Here's what $photostr is

```
 <a data-gallery="gallery" href="The_Great_Wave.jpg"  title=" The Great Wave off Kanagawa"> <img src="bar" alt=" The Great Wave off Kanagawa"/></a>
 <a data-gallery="gallery" href="Mt_Fuji.jpg"  title=" Mount Fuji (the highest mountain in Japan)"> <img src="bar" alt=" Mount Fuji (the highest mountain in Japan)"/></a>
 <a data-gallery="gallery" href="Beach.jpg"  title=" Waves Crashing on the Beach"> <img src="bar" alt=" Waves Crashing on the Beach"/></a>
 <a data-gallery="gallery" href="Elephant.jpg"  title=" An Elephant in the Serengeti"> <img src="bar" alt=" An Elephant in the Serengeti"/></a>
 <a data-gallery="gallery" href="Milky_Way.jpg"  title=" The Milky Way Galaxy (contains our Solar System)"> <img src="bar" alt=" The Milky Way Galaxy (contains our Solar System)"/></a>
 <a data-gallery="gallery" href="Poppies.jpg"  title=" Poppies in Bloom"> <img src="bar" alt=" Poppies in Bloom"/></a>
```

So it's chok full of meta characters, so I'm using pipes as delimeters, but I get this error...

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 70: unterminated `s' command
```

For input, $1 is a file that has html and some {{metatag}} in it that need appropriate substitutions to make a working webpage. The bit I'm concerned with,

`</a>
{{/each}}
      </div>`

should be turned into...

`</a>
-->
 <a data-gallery="gallery" href="The_Great_Wave.jpg"  title=" The Great Wave off Kanagawa"> <img src="bar" alt=" The Great Wave off Kanagawa"/></a>
 <a data-gallery="gallery" href="Mt_Fuji.jpg"  title=" Mount Fuji (the highest mountain in Japan)"> <img src="bar" alt=" Mount Fuji (the highest mountain in Japan)"/></a>
 <a data-gallery="gallery" href="Beach.jpg"  title=" Waves Crashing on the Beach"> <img src="bar" alt=" Waves Crashing on the Beach"/></a>
 <a data-gallery="gallery" href="Elephant.jpg"  title=" An Elephant in the Serengeti"> <img src="bar" alt=" An Elephant in the Serengeti"/></a>
 <a data-gallery="gallery" href="Milky_Way.jpg"  title=" The Milky Way Galaxy (contains our Solar System)"> <img src="bar" alt=" The Milky Way Galaxy (contains our Solar System)"/></a>
 <a data-gallery="gallery" href="Poppies.jpg"  title=" Poppies in Bloom"> <img src="bar" alt=" Poppies in Bloom"/></a>`

Comment: What is the input and desired output?

Comment: edited with expected io

Comment: Why use sed and not an actual x/html processing/template language xpath,xquery,xslt,php,... ?

Comment: Because I was told that my technology stack was limited to bash. It seems like it would be a simple variable substitution with sed I'm just missing something basic.

Comment: Don't use regex for HTML, read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: Why vote to close this? It's a question about trying to solve a problem in sed. Even if it's not completely practical, I wish someone with more sed and bash experience than I could show either a complete or partial solution using sed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Encode the line breaks in the value of your variable as `\n` before you use it:

```
photostr=$(sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/\\n/g' <<< "$photostr")
sed "s|{{/each}}| -->\n $photostr |" $1
```